# How to share requests' Session object in a Flask app

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests

I have a Flask application that interfaces with an API protected by authentication.

So I have two logins to manage:

1. Login to the flask application
2. Login to the protected API

To manage my requests with the API, I use a `Session` from the `requests` library.

I would like to make my `Session` object shareable between requests and pages of my application to avoid having to login each time (which takes about 2 seconds).

Is there a standard way to do that?

I tried to send the `Session` object in cookies, in a `flask` session or in `flask.g`, but the object is not serializable.

Comment: Use [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/)

Comment: As I said, `requests.Session` is not serializable.

Comment: Please add the code you are trying and the traceback. [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)